# Rails. Cache a part of JSON responce

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, caching, serialization

The action is responses with large JSON object, which can be separated into dynamic and static parts.

```
 render :json => {:dynamic => someting, :static => huge_static_object}
```

Evaluation of static part take too long, so it cached.

```
 huge_static_object = Rails.cache.fetch(key) do
   do_something
 end

 render :json => {:dynamic => something, :static => huge_static_object}
```

Now rails deserialization one each reading from cache + serialization to JSON. So let's store results at the cache as JSON.

```
huge_static_object = Rails.cache.fetch(key) do
   do_something.to_json
 end

 render :json => {:dynamic => something, :static => huge_static_object}
```

Now we have a problem with serialization on render because dynamic part need to be serialized, but static part is already serialized string. So add a simple proxy class.

```
class JsonStringProxy

  def initialize arg
    @object = arg
  end

  def to_json(*args)
    self
  end

  def as_json(*args)
    self
  end

  def encode_json(*args)
    @object
  end

  def to_s
    @object
  end

end

 huge_static_object = Rails.cache.fetch(key) do
   do_something.to_json
 end

 render :json => {:dynamic => something, :static => JsonStringProxy.new(huge_static_object)}
```

**Now all work well, but may be any more easy way to do same?**

Comment: Did you manage to solve this issue? I'm facing the exact same problem and unsure what to do. Also, your proxy class didn't work for me, it causes a SystemStackError exception (stack level too deep). Can you make sure you posted the correct code for that? Thanks!

Comment: Append method to_s. All work fine for me.